# how to use conditional statement in gesture detector?

Tags: flutter, dart

Always else part is executing in gucture detector i want to add search
fuctinality in
my app through gesture detecter .i am new to flutter so plz anybody help me in
solving this out

```
                       *****************   gesture Detector**************
        GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    if ((searchcontroller.text).replaceAll(" ","")=="") {
                      print("blank search");
                    }

                    else{
                    getRecipe(searchcontroller.text);
                    }
                  },

             *****************  getRecipe function**************
              

       


       getRecipe(String query) async
       {
           String url="https://api.edamam.com/search? 
   q=$query&app_id=f4cedff1&app_key=6cc02af8656424d8654e112ccdae0754&from=0&to=3&calories=591-722&health=alcohol-free";

     Response response=await get(Uri.parse(url));
     Map data =jsonDecode(response.body);
     print(data);
  }
```

Comment: Prefer using `isEmpty` method of `String` to check whether the string is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
var query = searchController.text.trim();
```

Use the above code to remove any extra white spaces from start or end of the string.